# balancing not working mongodb sharded cluster 4.0.23

Tags: mongodb

Anybody seen this message before , it looks my sharded cluster cannot balance after I execute sh.startBalancer() with following message:

```
2021-09-23T08:41:41.674+0200 I SHARDING [Balancer] Balancer move config.system.sessions: [{ _id: MinKey }, { _id: { id: UUID("00400000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000") } }), from s0,
to s3 failed :: caused by :: OperationFailed: Data transfer error: migrate failed: InvalidUUID: Cannot create collection config.system.sessions because we already have an identic
ally named collection with UUID 17d65f57-09b7-4335-91d5-92ef073cb6b9, which differs from the 
donor's UUID a6c3c5c8-8424-4a06-96a1-4082c349c6ff. Manually drop the collection on this shard if it contains data from a previous incarnation of config.system.sessions
```

Any help will be highly appreciated?
Thanks

Comment: Manually drop the collection on this shard if it contains data from a previous incarnation of config.system.sessions

Comment: even with admin privileges not possible when cluster is up and running I guess I need to do in single node per shard? ( without sharding + replication enabled )

Comment: issue fixed with eleveted privileges ... , thanks @Joe!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue fixed via following steps:

1. Stop balancer.
2. Create temporary user with "__system" role in all shards affected primary.
3. Log in to every shard with the temporary user and drop the system.sessions collection from config database.
4. Start balancer.
5. After steps 1-4 all system.sessions located on shards will be auto recreated with the same uuid and this will allow the balancing to continue as usual.